# Adding a countdown to data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, sequence

I have a data.table to which I want to add a countdown until a value of 1 appears in the `flag` column.

```
dt = structure(list(date = structure(19309:19318, class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55af7de49cb0>)
> dt
          date flag
 1: 2022-11-13    0
 2: 2022-11-14    0
 3: 2022-11-15    0
 4: 2022-11-16    0
 5: 2022-11-17    0
 6: 2022-11-18    1
 7: 2022-11-19    0
 8: 2022-11-20    0
 9: 2022-11-21    0
10: 2022-11-22    1
```

Here is the expected output

```
          date flag countdown
 1: 2022-11-13    0 5
 2: 2022-11-14    0 4
 3: 2022-11-15    0 3
 4: 2022-11-16    0 2
 5: 2022-11-17    0 1
 6: 2022-11-18    1 0
 7: 2022-11-19    0 3
 8: 2022-11-20    0 2
 9: 2022-11-21    0 1
10: 2022-11-22    1 0
```

A data.table solution is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A data.table solution is not only preferred but also beautiful.

```r
library(data.table)

dt = structure(list(date = structure(19309:19318, class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c( 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

setDT(dt)

dt[, countdown := rev(1:.N), by=rleid(flag)][flag==1, countdown:=0 ]
dt
#>           date flag countdown
#>  1: 2022-11-13    0         5
#>  2: 2022-11-14    0         4
#>  3: 2022-11-15    0         3
#>  4: 2022-11-16    0         2
#>  5: 2022-11-17    0         1
#>  6: 2022-11-18    1         0
#>  7: 2022-11-19    0         3
#>  8: 2022-11-20    0         2
#>  9: 2022-11-21    0         1
#> 10: 2022-11-22    1         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**edit**

```
dt[, countdown := .N:1 * !flag, by=rleid(flag)]
```

for brevity.

Comment: No i dont. What is the warning? I'm using 4.2.1 and data.table `installed.packages()["data.table","Version"] == "1.14.2"`

Comment: Oh, you do get a warning when you use OP's repro data without setDT step.

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option

```
> cbind(dt, dt[, .(countdonwn = .N - seq(.N)), rev(cumsum(rev(flag)))][, 2])
          date flag countdonwn
 1: 2022-11-13    0          5
 2: 2022-11-14    0          4
 3: 2022-11-15    0          3
 4: 2022-11-16    0          2
 5: 2022-11-17    0          1
 6: 2022-11-18    1          0
 7: 2022-11-19    0          3
 8: 2022-11-20    0          2
 9: 2022-11-21    0          1
10: 2022-11-22    1          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sequence`:

```
dt[ , countdown := {
  ix = which(flag == 1)
  v = ix - c(1, head(ix, -1) + 1)
  sequence(v + 1, v, -1L)
}]

          date flag countdown
 1: 2022-11-13    0         5
 2: 2022-11-14    0         4
 3: 2022-11-15    0         3
 4: 2022-11-16    0         2
 5: 2022-11-17    0         1
 6: 2022-11-18    1         0
 7: 2022-11-19    0         3
 8: 2022-11-20    0         2
 9: 2022-11-21    0         1
10: 2022-11-22    1         0
```

---

Using `rleid` and `rowid`:

```
dt[ , countdown := {rf = rev(flag); rev(rowid(rleid(rf)) * !rf)}]
```

---

Both alternatives are considerably faster on larger data:

```
n = 1e7
set.seed(1)
d = data.table(flag = c(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.2), 1))

d1 = copy(d)
d2 = copy(d)
d3 = copy(d)
d4 = copy(d)

microbenchmark(
  ric = d1[, r := .N:1 * !flag, by=rleid(flag)],
  thomas = {d2_2 = cbind(d2, d2[, .(r = .N - seq(.N)), rev(cumsum(rev(flag)))][, 2])},
  h1 = d4[ , r := {
    ix = which(flag == 1)
    v = ix - c(1, head(ix, -1) + 1)
    sequence(v + 1, v, -1L)
  }],
  h2 = d3[ , r := {rf = rev(flag); rev(rowid(rleid(rf)) * !rf)}],
  times = 10L)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    ric  3349.0538  3693.8509  3707.6691  3720.3821  3777.8165  3923.4453    10
 thomas 12914.1821 12942.3472 13049.8039 12985.2630 13162.3061 13359.6016    10
     h1   107.5380   109.0322   140.6891   110.0880   120.4707   261.9755    10
     h2   261.1989   283.2164   310.9347   293.2629   337.0358   431.7687    10

all.equal(d1, d2_2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(d1, d3)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(d1, d4)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, Henrik for a fast solution. Can you please add some explanation about statement - ```v = ix - c(1, head(ix, -1) + 1)``` in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Saurabh. I'm currently busy at work, but will add some explanation as soon as I can. Cheers